# Is there any physical advantage in placing the sample between the recombined beam and the detector in Fourier Transform spectrometry?

Tags: fourier-transform, spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

Usually, in all the implementations of FT spectroscopy the sample is always placed between the recombined beam and the detector like in this figure from Wikipedia:

[image: Michelson interferometer]

Theoretically, the interferometer should work also if the sample is placed directly after the light source. I was wondering if there is some physical reason for not using this configuration.